Setting the Y-axis in 1-step increments
I'm trying to set this graph to make 1 step increments on the Y axis all the way up to 13.
The problem seems to be it wants to go 0, 2, 4, 6, 8...
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{lua debug}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \begin{axis}[ xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}
    ,axis lines=middle
    ,samples=41,
    height=13cm,width=13cm,
    domain=-6:6,y domain=-10:10,
    grid,
    thick
    ,legend pos=outer north east
    ]
    \addplot+[no marks]{
      0.5*x^2
    };
    \addplot+ coordinates {
      (-5,12.5)(-4, 8) (-3,4.5)(-2,2)(-1,0.5) (0,0) (1,0.5) (2,2) (3,4.5) (4,8) (5,12.5)
    };
    \pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{1}
    \addlegendentry{$0.5x^2$}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \begin{axis}[ xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}
    ,axis lines=middle
    ,samples=41,
    height=13cm,width=13cm,
    domain=-5:5,y domain=-1:1,
    grid,
    thick
    ,legend pos=outer north east
    ]
    \addplot+[no marks]{
      2*x+3
    };
  \addlegendentry{$2x+3$}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



You could use the ytick distance=... option to set the distance between the y ticks:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{lua debug}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \begin{axis}[ xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}
    ,axis lines=middle
    ,samples=41,
    height=13cm,width=13cm,
    domain=-6:6,y domain=-10:10,
    grid,
    thick,
    legend pos=outer north east,
    ytick distance=1
    ]
    \addplot+[no marks]{
      0.5*x^2
    };
    \addplot+ coordinates {
      (-5,12.5)(-4, 8) (-3,4.5)(-2,2)(-1,0.5) (0,0) (1,0.5) (2,2) (3,4.5) (4,8) (5,12.5)
    };
    \pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{1}
    \addlegendentry{$0.5x^2$}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Ah I knew it was something simple!
